# PyQt5: How can I make a circle shaped app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to make PyQt5 app in circular shape. Something like this:

[image: Expected design].

I have created a basic layout with qtDesigner to test.
It contains a QFrame (named "mainFrame") whick I made circular with stylesheet.

I tried the same with mainWindow...
But, I can't figure out how to make empty mainWindow invisible.

I made window frameless, changed its opacity - but it affected everything inside mainWindow

basic test app:

[image: App design].

Code:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(500, 500)
        self.mainFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.mainFrame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 481, 481))
        self.mainFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.mainFrame.setObjectName("mainFrame")
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QFrame#mainFrame {\n"
        "    border: 5px solid grey;\n"
        "    border-radius: 240px;\n"
        "    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 50);\n"
        "}\n"
        "QWidget#Form {\n"
        "    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
        "    border: 5px solid grey;\n"
        "    border-radius: 250px;\n"
        "}")
        self.mainFrame.mouseDoubleClickEvent = lambda event: QtWidgets.qApp.quit()
        # Form.setWindowOpacity(0.4)
        # self.mainFrame.setWindowOpacity(1)
```

How can I make just the circular mainFrame to appear, and every thing within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `QRegion`::QRegion(const QRect &r, QRegion::RegionType t = Rectangle)
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Create a region based on the rectange r with region type t.
>
> If the rectangle is invalid a null region will be created.

---

> `QWidget`::setMask(const QRegion &region)
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Causes only the parts of the widget which overlap region to be visible. If the region includes pixels outside the rect() of the widget, window system controls in that area may or may not be visible, depending on the platform.
>
> Note that this effect can be slow if the region is particularly complex.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegion


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(500, 500)
        self.mainFrame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.mainFrame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 481, 481))
        self.mainFrame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.mainFrame.setObjectName("mainFrame")
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        Form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QFrame#mainFrame {\n"
        "    border: 5px solid grey;\n"
        "    border-radius: 240px;\n"
        "    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 50);\n"
        "}\n"
        "QWidget#Form {\n"
        "    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
        "    border: 5px solid grey;\n"
        "    border-radius: 250px;\n"
        "}")
        self.mainFrame.mouseDoubleClickEvent = lambda event: QtWidgets.qApp.quit()
        # Form.setWindowOpacity(0.4)
        # self.mainFrame.setWindowOpacity(1)
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.region_and_mask()

    def region_and_mask(self):
        my_region = QRegion(self.rect(), QRegion.Ellipse)
        self.setMask(my_region)        


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]